# Task.Delay inside thread C#

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, task

I'm working in a `WPF` application where i'm making a save process inside a thread. After the save process i'm initiating the load process between that i need a delay so i used the `Task.Delay` method.

During the save/load a progress bar is shown in the application untill it completes. Now when i use the `Task.Delay` method for 2 seconds no progress bar is shown in the application.

Now the issue is the delay(2 seconds). When there is a delay the user starts using the application and suddenly the load process starts.

So i need to make the `Task.Delay` method to be inside a `Thread` so that i can show the progress bar for that delay too.

I tried the following code but it throws me a warning,

//ViewModel Code:

```
 BackgroundWorker bw;
 async System.Threading.Tasks.Task PutTaskDelay()  //warning here
        {
            bw = new BackgroundWorker();
            IsBusy = true;        // to show the progress bar
            bw.RunWorkerAsync();

            bw.DoWork += async (s, e) =>
            {
                await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(2000);
            };

            bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) =>
            {
                IsBusy = false;   // Hide the progress bar
            };
        }
```

**Warning:**

```
The async method lacks await operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the async operator to await non-blocking API calls, or await Task.Run(...) to do CPU-bound work on a backgrond thread.
```

If there is alternate method let me know.

Comment: What is the purpose of the two-second delay? IMHO, if you've got a problem you think you've solved by the equivalent of `Thread.Sleep`, then you probably don't understand the problem.

Comment: @moswald: I need the delay after the thread completes its process. So i'm unable to use `Thread.Sleep`. May be i don't. Can you please share some modified code of mine so that i might be clear.

Comment: That's what I mean, why do you say you need the delay after the thread completes it's process?

Comment: At times the load process gets initiated before the save completes. The delay works at that time.

Comment: It sounds like you 1) start saving then 2) start loading, but they aren't tied together. To fix this, you 1) start saving, 2) start sleeping 2 seconds, then 3) start loading. This is a race condition that you're just making less likely, but you aren't actually fixing. You should rewrite your save/load logic so that the load doesn't start until the save is guaranteed to be finished. The `Task.Delay` might be working on your dev environment, but it's not guaranteed to work every time.

Comment: Yes, this is what i'm doing now. Is there anyway that i can rewirte the logic? Just an description is enough. Kindly help.

Comment: You will need to edit your post to include more code to see how you do your saving and loading logic. We can't tell what you're doing just from the sleep method.

Comment: Will post it ASAP, thanks.

Comment: @moswald : I have posted this as a new question. Kindly take a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35884884/concurrent-multi-threading-c-sharp

Comment: You should not mix background worker and async programming. It is much harder to understand what happen when you don't follow either model but do a mix of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BackgroundWorker` is obsolete. Use async methods in combination with `Task.Run` instead and the problem goes away.

Comment: Can you please post a sample?

Comment: Does that (https://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en&gws_rd=ssl#complete=1&hl=en&q=wpf+task.run+await) help?

Answer (score 0):

Your first `async` isn't required because you don't use `await`. That's what the warning is telling you.

This is the equivalent to what you've originally posted, with a lot less work involved. Note that `async` is now required.

```
async Task PutTaskDelayAsync()   // convention is to name async methods with Async suffix
{
    IsBusy = true;
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    IsBusy = false;
}
```

Comment: This doesnt makes the progress bar come. Only when there is a `BackgroundWorker` running the progress bar arrives.